# ASP.NET Web Api (RTW) Causes errors in test - "Post is not supported by language"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I had previously been developing with the beta version of asp.net web api (in the asp.net mvc 4 packaged) and everything was working ok. I also had some tests which basically created a controller and called Post or Get on the controller.

Now these are giving me errors saying

> Post is not supported by language
>
> or
>
> Get is not supported by language

If I remove the test project then all is OK and I can build my web api project and it works.

But my tests constantly error. I have even deleted my test project and re-created it from scratch and still the same.

All I am doing is creating an instance of the controller and calling Get / Post which are actual methods on the controllers.

Comment: Are you using MVC 4 for your solution or the web api for MVC 3?

Comment: It was the latest beta that i built the project with so it was an asp.net mvc4 site where you can choose type of site from the dialog i.e. Web Api

Answer (score 0):

He is an example unit test for a Web API controller using the default WebAPI project for MVC 4 tested with NUnit and Moq.

```
//ValuesController.cs in GetPostExample project
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace GetPostExample.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post(string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}

//AGetPostValuesControllerShould.cs in GetPostExampleTest project
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using GetPostExample.Controllers;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace GetPostExampleTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AGetPostValuesControllerShould
    {
        private Mock<HttpControllerContext> _controllerContext;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            _controllerContext = new Mock<HttpControllerContext>();
            _controllerContext.SetupAllProperties();
        }

        [Test]
        public void WhenAGetRequestIsCalledToValuesontrollerItShouldReturnAnArrayOfValues()
        {
            var expected = new[] {"value1", "value2"};

            var valuesController = new ValuesController {ControllerContext = _controllerContext.Object};
            var result = valuesController.Get();

            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expected));
        }
    }
}
```